# Simplifying factorials in the Bessel polynomials

Tags: special-functions, factorial, bessel-functions

Consider the generating formula for the Bessel polynomials (increasing coefficients):

$$a_k=\frac{(N+k)!}{2^kk!(N-k)!}$$

I was trying to generate as high an order as possible with `unsigned int` ($2^{32}-1=4294967295$) in C++. The theoretical maximum should be for $N=10$ when $a_N=654729075$ (for $N=11$, $a_N=13749310575>4294967295$). I realize there are multiplications before divisions, so some higher value must be reached first before the final result, but I tried to expand the products and manually simplify the formula (a "spot the pattern" game), and I got to this point:

$$a_k=\frac{\prod_{i=max(N-k,k)+1}^{N+k}{i}}{2^k\prod_{i=1}^{min(k,N-k)}{i}}$$

Which works until $N=8$. This can be simplified even more considering that the denominator has powers of 2 that can be completely eliminated, and the rest of the terms which will end up perfectly dividing all the terms in the numerator. This leaves a simple product, but which doesn't have quite so recognizable patterns. Here is what wxMaxima outputs for $N=10$ (aligned to $11$, I don't know how to add spaces to have a match for every index):

$$\begin{align}
& 1 \\\\
5\cdot&11 \\\\
3\cdot5\cdot9\cdot&11 \\\\
2^2\cdot5\cdot9\cdot&11\cdot13 \\\\
5\cdot7^2\cdot9\cdot&11\cdot13 \\\\
3\cdot7^2\cdot9\cdot&11\cdot13\cdot15 \\\\
2^2\cdot5\cdot7^2\cdot9\cdot&11\cdot13\cdot15 \\\\
2^3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot9\cdot&11\cdot13\cdot15\cdot17 \\\\
3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot9^2\cdot&11\cdot13\cdot15\cdot17 \\\\
3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot9\cdot&11\cdot13\cdot15\cdot17\cdot19 \\\\
3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot9\cdot&11\cdot13\cdot15\cdot17\cdot19
\end{align}
$$

It's a crippled product of odd numbers, some repeating, and some even number squeezing in; the residuals of simplification.

Since the above seemed too much to implement in programming, I tried a recursive approach:

$$\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}=\frac{(N-i)(N+1+i)}{2i+2}$$

Which goes until $N=9$. I realize this is a bit of a whim, since there are builtin higher precision `int`s, and, if not, there's [gmp](https://gmplib.org), or similar, but my question is: can the formula be simplified even more? I am referring to the generating, not the recursive formula. Also, no tables.

Answer (score 1):

In my humble opinion,  computing first
$$b_k=\log(\Gamma(N+k+1))-k\log(2)-\log(\Gamma(k+1))-\log(\Gamma(N-k+1))$$ using the *LnGamma(x)* function could be a way.

Then, $a_k=e^{b_k}$.

Comment: This is a nice workaround, and it certainly works without overflow (just tried it), unfortunately it also means using `double`, instead of `int`. But rounding could be used, true. OTOH, I've been thinking about it, and there doesn't seem to be a clean solution, since, even if I can divide by 2, the numerator would have to be twice as big, already. Unless there is a way to spot a pattern in the "crippled product" -- which I doubt.

Comment: That would certainly give a good estimate but I don't think it would be good enough to get the prime factors.

Comment: @martycohen. I fully agree